# Why does the pagination stop working when I filter?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have made a basic code that displays an array of objects and you can filter these objects by selecting checkboxes. The array is quite big so I added a code that paginates the array over multiple pages, this works when the code is first run but then stops when a filter is applied. Why?

```
function filterAccommodations(jsonData, selectedTypes, selectedPriceRanges, selectedLocations) {
  
  let filteredAccommodations = jsonData;

  if (selectedTypes.length > 0) {
    filteredAccommodations = filteredAccommodations.filter(jsonData => selectedTypes.includes(jsonData.Industry));
  }


  if (selectedPriceRanges.length > 0) {
    filteredAccommodations = filteredAccommodations.filter(jsonData => {
      return selectedPriceRanges.some(priceRange => {
        const rangeParts = priceRange.split("-");
        const min = parseInt(rangeParts[0].replace('R', ''));
        const max = parseInt(rangeParts[1].replace('R', '')) || Infinity;
        return jsonData.Price >= min && jsonData.Price <= max;
      });
    });
  }

  
  if (selectedLocations.length > 0) {
    filteredAccommodations = filteredAccommodations.filter(jsonData => selectedLocations.includes("Any") || selectedLocations.includes(jsonData.Town));
  }

  



  // Return the filtered accommodations
  return filteredAccommodations;
}



let selectedTypes = [];
let selectedPriceRanges = [];
let selectedLocations = []; 
let selectedIndustry = [];



//sorting by type e.g. lodge, hotel, self-catering
var typeCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.type')

for(let typeCheckbox of typeCheckboxes) {
  typeCheckbox.addEventListener('click',function() {

    
    if(this.checked == true){
      let value = this.getAttribute('value')
      selectedTypes.push(this.value);
      console.log(this.value);
      
    } else if(this.checked == false){
      selectedTypes = selectedTypes.filter(e => e !== this.value);
    }
    displaySelectedTypes();
    displayFilteredAccommodations();
  })}


  //for price ranges
  var priceCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.price')

for(let priceCheckbox of priceCheckboxes) {
  priceCheckbox.addEventListener('click',function() {

    
    if(this.checked == true){
      let value = this.getAttribute('value')
      selectedPriceRanges.push(this.value);
      console.log(this.value);
      
    } else if(this.checked == false){
      selectedPriceRanges = selectedPriceRanges.filter(e => e !== this.value);
    }
    displaySelectedPrice();
    displayFilteredAccommodations();
  })}

  //for location
  var locationCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.location')

  for(let locationCheckbox of locationCheckboxes) {
    locationCheckbox.addEventListener('click',function() {
  
      
      if(this.checked == true){
        let value = this.getAttribute('value')
        selectedLocations.push(this.value);
        console.log(this.value);
        
      } else if(this.checked == false){
        selectedLocations = selectedLocations.filter(e => e !== this.value);
      }
      displaySelectedLocations();
      displayFilteredAccommodations();
    })}
  

  console.log(selectedLocations)
  
  
   function displaySelectedTypes() {
    console.log("Updated selectedTypes:", selectedTypes);
  }

  function displaySelectedPrice() {
    console.log("updated price", selectedPriceRanges)
  }

  function displaySelectedLocations() {
    console.log("updated locations", selectedLocations)
  }


  function displayFilteredAccommodations() {
    const filteredAccommodations = filterAccommodations(jsonData, selectedTypes, selectedPriceRanges, selectedLocations);
    console.log("Updated filteredAccommodations:", filteredAccommodations);
  }



const filteredAccommodations = filterAccommodations(jsonData, selectedTypes, selectedPriceRanges, selectedLocations);

console.log(selectedTypes);
console.log(filteredAccommodations);

 // Function to create and populate data elements
 function displayFilteredAccommodations() {
  const filteredAccommodations = filterAccommodations(jsonData, selectedTypes, selectedPriceRanges, selectedLocations);
  console.log("Updated filteredAccommodations:", filteredAccommodations);

  // Clear the previous results
  const container = document.getElementById('data-container');
  container.innerHTML = '';

  // Create and populate data elements for the filtered accommodations
  filteredAccommodations.forEach(function (item) {
    const dataItem = document.createElement('div');
    dataItem.className = 'item';
    dataItem.innerHTML = '<h2>' + item.Name + '</h2>' + 
      '<p><strong>Industry</strong> ' + item.Industry + '</p>' +
      '<p><strong>Location:</strong> ' + item.Town + '</p>' +
      '<p><strong>Tags:</strong> ' + item.Tags + '</p>' +
      '<p><strong>Price:</strong> R' + item.Price + '</p>';

    container.appendChild(dataItem);
  });


  const pageNumbers = document.querySelector(".pageNumbers");
const paginationList = document.getElementById("data-container");
const listItems = paginationList.querySelectorAll(".item");
const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev");
const nextButton = document.getElementById("next");

const contentLimit = 10;
const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / contentLimit);
let currentPage = 1;

const displayPageNumbers = (index) =>{
    const pageNumber = document.createElement("a");
    pageNumber.innerText = index;
    pageNumber.setAttribute('href', "#");
    pageNumber.setAttribute("index", index);
    pageNumbers.appendChild(pageNumber);
};

const getPageNumbers = ()=>{
    for(let i=1; i <= pageCount; i++){
        displayPageNumbers(i);
    };
};

const disableButton = (button) =>{
    button.classList.add("disabled");
    button.setAttribute("disabled", true);
};

const enableButton = (button) =>{
    button.classList.remove("disabled");
    button.removeAttribute("disabled");
};

const controlButtonsStatus = () =>{
    if(currentPage == 1){
        disableButton(prevButton);
    }
    else{
        enableButton(prevButton);
    }
    if(pageCount == currentPage){
        disableButton(nextButton);
    }
    else{
        enableButton(nextButton);
    }
};

const handleActivePageNumber = () =>{
    document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((button) =>{
        button.classList.remove("active");
        const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute("index"));
        if(pageIndex == currentPage){
            button.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
};

const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) =>{
    currentPage = pageNum;

    handleActivePageNumber();
    controlButtonsStatus();

    const prevRange = (pageNum -1) * contentLimit;
    const currRange = pageNum * contentLimit;

    listItems.forEach((item, index) =>{
        item.classList.add('hidden');
        if(index >= prevRange && index < currRange){
            item.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    });
};

window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
    getPageNumbers();
    setCurrentPage(1);

    prevButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    });

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((button) =>{
        const pageIndex = Number(button.getAttribute('index'));

        if(pageIndex){
            button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                setCurrentPage(pageIndex);
            });
        };
    });
  });
}
displayFilteredAccommodations();
```

I tried changing getting it to use the filteredAccomodations but it doesn't work. I have never really used JavaScript so I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Can you add the code to jsfiddle, or any online editor and share the URL

Comment: Filtering changes the objects size so I would guess that pagination is assuming ALL items, not the custom-search/filtered items.